# Jquery Datatable data is not getting aligned with the table header

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

using JQuery Datatable we are trying to row grouping and facing the below issue - table header and data is not getting aligned properly as shown in the below image tried setting css property,adjusting the width of the header. but datatable is not taking the width.[DataTable grid width issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukrsi.png)

below is the sample code by which we populate the data grid

cshtml code

```
<html>
<div hidden id="div-summary-table-SelfApp">
    <table class="table table-border table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" width="140%" cellspacing="0" id="summary-table-selfApp" style="border-bottom: none !important;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("eventinfo")</th>
            <th colspan="6">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("roleInformation")</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("eventID")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("eventname")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("eventdate")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("holdingarea")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("nameofapplicant")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("event_applicationstatus")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("event_reportingstatus")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("performername")</th>
            <th rowspan="2">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("nameoffacility")</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="4">@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("status")</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("policy")</th>
            <th>@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("arrangementoftranspotation")</th>
            <th>@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("slidebeforetheevent")</th>
            <th>@SharedLocalizer.GetLocalizedHtmlString("slideontheday")</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>   
</div>
</html>
`
```

js code

```
`

     $("#summary-table-selfApp").DataTable({
                    "dom": '<"top"li>rt<"bottom"p>',
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "test/data",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "dataType": "JSON",
                        "data": function (filterParam) {
                            filterParam.EventID = EventIDSA;
                            filterParam.EventName = EventNameSA;
                            filterParam.Applicant = ApplicantSA;
                            filterParam.ApplicantBranchName = ApplicantBranchSA;
                            filterParam.ApplicantDepartmentName = drpDeptSelfApp;
                            filterParam.SearchOrganization = OrganizationSA;
                            filterParam.Status = StatusSA;
                            filterParam.EventType = EventTypeSA;
                            filterParam.EventSubType = EventSubTypeSA;
                            filterParam.HowToHold = HowToHoldSA;
                            filterParam.HoldingArea = HoldingAreaSA;
                            filterParam.ProductName = ProductNameSA;
                            filterParam.HoldingFormat = HoldingFormatSA;
                            filterParam.Role = isUserId;
                            filterParam.ExpertName = ExpertNameSA;
                            filterParam.FacilityName = FacilityNameSA;
                            filterParam.CostCenter = CostCenterSa;
                            filterParam.ActivityWBSName = ActivityWBSSA;
                            filterParam.SearchType = SearchType;
                            filterParam.UserID = isLoggedId;
                            filterParam.EventFromDate = EventFrmDate;
                            filterParam.EventToDate = EventToDate;
                            filterParam.PersonInCharge = PersonInChargeSA;
                            filterParam.IsExceptionApp = ExceptionApp;
                            filterParam.ReportApproval = ReportApproval;
                            filterParam.MonitoringFrmDate = MonitoringFrmDate;
                            filterParam.MonitoringToDate = MonitoringToDate;
                            filterParam.RefetchData = refetchData;
                            filterParam.SlideBeforeEvent = SlideBeforeEvent;
                            filterParam.SlideOnTheDay = SlideOnTheDay;
                            filterParam.ApplicantBusinessUnit = BusinessUnitSA;
                        },
                    },
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "language": {
                        "search": "Filter records:",
                        "paginate": {
                            "first": "<<",
                            "previous": "<",
                            "next": ">",
                            "last": ">>"
                        },
                        "emptyTable": "レコードがありません。",
                        "lengthMenu": "表示件数 _MENU_/ページ",
                        "info": "<b>_TOTAL_</b> 件のうち <b>_START_</b> から <b>_END_</b> 件 を表示",
                        "infoEmpty": ""
    
                    },
                    "rowsGroup": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                        refetchData = false;
                        if ($(this).find('.dataTables_empty').length == 1) {
                            $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
                            $('.dataTables_info').hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.dataTables_paginate').show();
                            $('.dataTables_info').show();
                        }
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "eventIdUrl", "name": "eventIdUrl", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "eventName", "name": "eventName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "eventDateStr", "name": "eventDateStr", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "holdingArea", "name": "holdingArea", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "applicant", "name": "applicant", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "eventAppStatus", "name": "eventAppStatus", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "eventRepStatus", "name": "eventRepStatus", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "performerName", "name": "performerName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "workfacility", "name": "workfacility", "autoWidth": true },
                        {
                            "name": "policy", "autoWidth": true,
                            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                                return '<a class="properName" target="_blank" href="/contract/contractdetails?EventExpertId=' + row.expertId + '">' + row.policy + '</a>'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "transportation", "autoWidth": true,
                            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                                return '<a class="properName" target="_blank" href="/Travel/ParticipantTravelRequestForm?eventId=' + row.eventId + '&expert_id=' + row.expertId + '">' + row.transportation + '</a>'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "slideStatusBefore", "autoWidth": true,
                            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                                return '<a class="properName" target="_blank" href="' + srsSlideUrl + row.eventId + '&expert_id=' + row.slideExpertId + '">' + row.slideStatusBefore + '</a>'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "slideStatusAfter", "autoWidth": true,
                            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                                return '<a class="properName" target="_blank" href="' + srsSlideUrl + row.eventId + '&expert_id=' + row.slideExpertId + '">' + row.slideStatusAfter + '</a>'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });`
```

could you help how to set the data gets align with the header dynamically